# How to get the id of an item in an array?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = document.getElementById('abc');
alert(a.id) // it works.

var b = document.getElementsByClassName('qwe');
alert(b[0].id); // this is not working. returns only empty space : ''
```

I don't know why this happening.

a is object, and b is array object. and b[0] is object property. and also object.

Is there any one who can explain this happening's reason and solution clearly?

ps. sorry for miss 'document'. I missed it when I write this question. but in the source code, I didn't miss it.

```
<html>
<div id="abc" class="qwe"></div>
<div id="a1" class="qwe"></div>
<div id="a2" class="qwe"></div>
<div id="a3" class="qwe"></div>
```

Comment: place your html too.

Comment: I think this case doesn't need an html..but I'll add it more detailed description.

Comment: Are you sure the first selected element with class of `qwe` has ID property?

Comment: Something else is going on, putting your code exactly as-is in a JSFiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/8qf69aj7/

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot. Your comment was very helpful to solve the problem. I looked my source again, and I found that I didn't put id in that elements... thanks again.

Comment: It is best to leave the question as it originally was.Do not correct questions to reflect the solution.You can mention how the answer helped you in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

if you write `document` before getElementById it should work fine .

Here is jsBin example  [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/zatubejuhepo/1/)

```
var a = document.getElementById('abc');
alert(a.id) // it works.

var b = document.getElementsByClassName('qwe');
alert(b[0].id); // this is not working. returns only empty space : ''
```

Comment: you can check on jsbin.. copy paste not my work man

Comment: Check the OP's edit, they claim that they had in fact included `document`.

Answer (score 0):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jcsxaL4/)

You forget to use `document` before `getElementById` and `getElementsByClassName`, other wise its working fine. check out above jsfidlle link

Comment: Check the OP's edit, they claim that they had in fact included `document`.

Comment: Yes, now it is working fine....http://jsfiddle.net/8qf69aj7/